# RadioButton in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to swift and just embeded a [SSRadioButtonsController](https://github.com/shamasshahid/SSRadioButtonsController)  in Xcode now I want this to be displayed with some text in a `UIAlertView`.

I have done this but it doesn't work at all.

```
   @IBAction func infoClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    self.displayAlert("My Health Action Plan Detail", message: "A Health Action Plan is personal plan describing what you need to do to stay healthy. Using the plan can help you focus your health activities.")

    var radioButtonController = SSRadioButtonsController()
    radioButtonController.setButtonsArray([button1!,button2!,button3!])
    var currentButton = radioButtonController.selectedButton()
}
```

I need to display some radio buttons with text alongside in alert view

Comment: You cannot add interface a UIAlertView, and in any case UIAlertView is totally dead: you should be using UIAlertController. But in _your_ case you should be using a custom presented view controller.

Comment: Ok i got it.But please help me to add the radio buttons :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @matt said You cannot add interface a UIAlertView or UIAlertController. And you can add ssradion button  to view like this.

```
        let radioButton = SSRadioButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 20 ))
        radioButton.circleRadius = 8
        radioButton.circleColor = UIColor.redColor()
       radioButton.setTitle("1", forState: .Normal)
        radioButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)

        let radioButton1 = SSRadioButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 20 ))
        radioButton1.circleRadius = 8
        radioButton1.circleColor = UIColor.redColor()
        radioButton1.setTitle("2", forState: .Normal)
        radioButton1.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)

 var radioButtonController = SSRadioButtonsController(buttons: radioButton, radioButton1)
 radioBtnController.delegate = self
```

add radiobutton to view

```
self.view.addSubView(radioButton)
self.view.addSubView(radioButton1)
```

and if you want to detect which button is clicked you need to implement `SSRadioButtonControllerDelegate` method `didSelectButton`.

Comment: So what is the invalid decleration for the radioButton,radioButton1? i have used     @IBOutlet weak var radioButton: SSRadioButton!
but it shows error

Comment: yes i fix this issue by keeping it inside ViewDIdLoad but why cant i see any buttons inside the after running application